# apply permission and creating query

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, acl

I am coding a php application which has 4 level of users
admin,manager,group,client
admin will create managers, manager will create group.
All except client can create clients
I have a user table with following fields among others
ID primary auto
user_name varchar unique
managerid
groupid
usertype int (one among 4 type)

If a client does not belong to any manager or group under a manager managerid and groupid will be 0
if client belong to a group it will be assigned groupid
if group  belong to a manager it will be assigned a managerid
So a manager can have many groups and a group can have multiple clients
Site starts with login page, on successful login depending upon usertype home page will display a list of clients.
IF its an individual client it will show thier name only.
if its a group it will display all client under their group and individual created by them
if its a manager it should display all client under all their group and individual created by them.
What i am looking for is an optimized way to achieve this workflow.
I can get the list of admin (it will be all),list of group - everyone having their group id
But i am a bit confused about how managers list will be created.
I can find a list that have managerid and no groupid for individual and first find out group under this manger and get all client having these group id.But i think this can be
achieved with sql query I need help in building such a query.
If possible i would like to work out a query which will get me this list.
I am using codeIgniter to build this site.
So if query is adopted for CI it will be magnificent.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
      SELECT * 
      from 
          UserTable
      WHERE 
          groupid 
      in (select groupid from UserTable where managerid='id')
```

---

Below code can be used to get data from active record

```
      $this->db->select('u1.*');
      $this->db->from('UserTable u1');
      $this->db->join('UserTable u2', 'u1.groupid = u2.groupid');
      $this->db->where('u2.managerid', $id);
      $this->db->get();
```

This will generate below query

```
      SELECT `u1`.* 
      FROM (`UserTable` u1) 
      JOIN `UserTable` u2 ON `u1`.`groupid` = `u2`.`groupid` 
      WHERE `u2`.`managerid` = 1
```

Comment: Yes that would be the sql query to get result for a particular id . I wanted to know how that would be applied for active record in codeigniter.But still its a good lead and would work on this direction.
Hope someone has some answer for first part of the question.

Comment: I have added a new query and active record code the  result will be same as earlier query.